# Poisson process jump rate

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Claim 1: $q\left ( i,j \right )=\lambda u\left ( i,j \right )$
>
> where $q\left ( i,j \right )$ is the jump rate for a Markov chain at initial state i to a final state j in one step and $u\left ( i,j \right )$ is the associated transition probability for a Markov chain at an initial state i to a final state j in one step.
>
> Claim 2: For a Markov chain at initial state n and a final state n+1, the jump rate is $\lambda$, for all n $\geq 0$

Claim 2 implies that the transition probability from a state i to j in one step is one. How can I verify this?

Excerpt from *Essential of Stochastic Processes* by *Durrett*.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but it sounds like, in whatever process these claims describe, if you are in state $n$, you will go to the state $n+1$ with probability $1$. If this is a simple Poisson process, then the count eventually increases from $n$ to $n+1$ before going to any other states.

Comment: @stochastic
I can agree with transition probability one from state i to state j in one step - if stated - but this was not specify by the author. This is the source of confusion; there is no general rule dictating the transition probability from i to j in one step to be one.

Comment: In a jump process with time-independent rates, you eventually leave the current state. Therefore, the sum of transition probabilities out of a state has to be one. In the Poisson process, there is only one state that you can go to from state $n$, that is the state $n+1$. So the transition probability has to be one.

Comment: @stochastic Maybe I am overthinking but why does a Markov chain necessarily leave a state?
In a poisson process, why is there only one adjacent state to which a Markov chain may transit to?

Comment: Poisson process is a well defined specific process. It's the number of arrivals by time $t$ if arrivals happens with a constant rate $\lambda$. If $\lambda \neq 0$ the probability of the number not changing after a time interval $\tau$ is given by $e^{-\lambda\,\tau}$ which goes to zero as $\tau\to \infty$.

Comment: You're right that Markov chain doesn't always have to leave the state, but it does in Poisson process

Comment: @stochastic I'm still not bridging your argument to the claim.
From the principal definition, the number of arrival in a finite time t, N(t), is a poisson process. The probability of the number of arrival in a finite time interval t time being equal to some positive integer n is a poisson ($\lambda$ t) distribution. 
I'm not understanding how the zero limit of a finite time interval t relates the restriction of a Markov chain in a Poisson Process to only adjacent states.

Comment: The transition probability $u(n,n+1)$ is the conditional probability of transitioning to the state $n+1$ in one step (at some later time) given that you are at the state $n$ at time $t$. Suppose you are at state $n$ at time $t$, that is $n$th arrival happened at time $t$. What is going to happen next? Eventually, someone is going to arrive at some time $t+\tau$ by the above argument

Comment: @stochastic So your claim argues that as time $\tau$ tends to infinity, the probability that a Markov chain will not transition to another state at time t+$\tau$ is zero. In other words, there is a probability one that a Markov chain in the state at time t would transit to another state at time t +$\tau$ as $\tau$ tends to infinity. But what does this says anything about that "other state" being adjacent to the state at which the Markov chain is at time t?

Comment: The only allowed (one step) transition out of state $n$ in the Poisson process is to the state $n+1$ (this is a part of the definition of Poisson). So if the probability of not leaving state $n$ goes to zero at long time, at some point in finite time, the state has to transition from $n$ to $n+1.$

Comment: @stochastic I got it.